# How to write content in batch file with character \?

Tags: java

i'm trying to write content in a batch file with java and i'm not able to write this "\" it accepts only "/"

i tried this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\me\\test\\clean.bat", "UTF-8");
writer.println('forfiles /p C:\Users\me/source /m *.* /s /d -7 /c " cmd move @file c:\Users\archive"');
writer.close();
```

It does not accpet to write this C:\Users\me/source and this c:\Users\archive
It accepts to write only this:  C:/Users/me/source and this c:/Users/archive

The problem is batch cannot recognize /

Any help
Thank you

Comment: Escape slashes using a second slash.  I.e. `C:\\Users`

Comment: OK if i use a second like \\, it creates the file but cmd doesn't recognize \\, it says the directory is not valid

Comment: sorry it works, thank you